# Using random generator with probability using matlab

Tags: matlab, probability

THe following code generates random numbers with a given probability of success:

```
         n=[randi([0 1],1,8) ones(1,8)];
         n= n(randperm(10));
```

If the above lines are repeated random (unpridictable) values will be generated:

This is n for the first run:

```
 n =     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
```

This is n for the second run:

```
 n =     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

How can I make the generator picking the number of already selected as failure(0) with higher probability?

That is the probability person 2, 3 and 4 in the second round has more probability of loosing. This does not mean that they have to fail.

The entries 1 to 10 are 10 different user outputs.

ok let us say always a max of 30% of entries will be 0. In every time the above is executed. However this is done randomly. So a max of any 3 of the 10 can be zero.

I do not want the probability of success to change.Just to control which one is zero.

To clarify further What I want: If 3 will be chosen "randomly" to be zero then let the previously chosen three have higher probability to be picked and not be picked.

Comment: If you generate half of your vector as ones, you already have a sample with higher than 0.5 probability of success (actually 0.6). Please make your question clearer.

Comment: Do you mean the probability of persons 2, 4, and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with the following logic:

1. Generate up to 3 failures, assign them randomly
2. Decide how many failures are in step 2
3. Give the previous failures a higher chance to fail again

Note that I assume that it is equally likely to have 0,1,2, or 3 failures.

```
nRuns = 5;
allRuns = zeros(nRuns,10); %# stores success and failure for all runs

%# (1) generate from 0 to 3 failures (each outcome is equally likely)
nFailures = randi([0 3],1);
tmp = randperm(10);

firstRun = tmp > nFailures
allRuns(1,:) = firstRun;

%# (2) decide how many failures occur in the 2nd run (each outcome is equally likely)
for iRun = 2:nRuns
%# as the loop has been added later
%# I use "2" to indicate any next run
nFailures2 = randi([0 3],1);

%# (3) give previous failures a higher chance to fail again
failIdx = find(~allRuns(iRun-1,:));
successIdx = find(allRuns(iRun-1,:));
%# 5x higher chance of failing for previous failures
failCandidates = [repmat(failIdx,1,5),successIdx];

failCandidatesRand = failCandidates(randperm(length(failCandidates)));

%# if you have R2012a or later
failCandidatesRand = unique(failCandidatesRand ,'stable');
toFail = failCandidatesRand (1:nFailures2);

%# alternatively, if you have R2011b or earlier
toFail = zeros(nFailures2,1);
toFail(1) = failCandidatesRand(1);
ii = 2;
kk = 2;
while ii < (nFailures2+1)
if ~any(toFail==failCandidatesRand(kk));
toFail(ii) = failCandidatesRand(kk);
ii = ii + 1;
end
kk = kk + 1;
end

%# write failures
nextRun= true(1,10);
nextRun(toFail) = false

allRuns(iRun,:) = nextRun;
end
```

Comment: @pac: You can simply repeat the steps for run #2

Comment: Sorry but Can you be clearer @Jonas I am going to make it a function which part should I exclude from the function?Which should be the output so that it will be used in the call?

Comment: @pac: i have modified the code so that every run is dependent on the previous one.

Comment: @pac: The only time the code for the following runs needs the information from the previous run is where "allRuns" is accessed. Thus, it should be straightforward for you to copy the body of the loop and add it after the "several other functions" - all you need to replace are the lines where failIdx and successIdx are computed.

Comment: can we do nRuns=2 @Jonas to make it 1 RUN? Yes got your point but I did not want it to use it in the main body.This is why I prefered all to be 1 big function

Comment: ok how can I rerun from #2 and on again but this time instead of having argument firstrun have argument next run of the last run. Can this be performed @Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
n1 = rand(1, 8) > 0.5;
n2 = rand(1, 8) > (n1 * 0.5 + ~n1 * 0.6);
```

This would generate the first set of 0s and 1s with equal probability. For n2, if the corresponding value in n1 is 1, then there is 50% probability of 0 or 1. If the corresponding value in n1 = 0, then there is 60% probability of 0.

Thanks for  your clarification of the problem. Let's try again!
I think you can use [randsample](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/stats/randsample.html) for this. It is a bit messy because there doesn't seem to be an option for weighted sampling without replacement.

```
N = ones(1, 10);
for round=1:10
  failures = randi([1, 3]);
  indices = [];
  while (numel(unique(indices)) < failures)
    indices = randsample(10, failures, true, [N + ~N*1.1]);
  end
  N = ones(1, 10);
  N(indices) = 0;
  disp(N);
end
```

Comment: You are changing the probability of success. I am using the same code.Just generating it several times.The probability of failure is always <x

Comment: indices is used in the while which is not defined @Richante

Comment: always giving ones 10*10 @Richante